# How can I intercept an item being crafted and replace it with something with a 'canplaceon' tag?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to detect when someone is building a lever, then replace it with another lever that has the `canplaceon` tag so it can be placed on a redstone_lamp

How can I clear the crafting item and replace it with one that has a `canplaceon` tag?

Comment: Items in a crafting table aren't saved to the save file and you can't detect them with commands. Would it also work for you if the lever got the "CanPlaceOn" tag when the player is just holding it? Otherwise you could look into "Custom crafting" systems, but they are more complicated.

Comment: i see some custom maps when i craft a lever remove it and add new item with canplaceon tag

Comment: Then just look at their commands. Or ask the creator.

Comment: *[Comments cleaned up]* - I have incorporated the clarifying comments into the question. @guest please check this over and edit your question if anything is incorrect or you have any additional info.

Answer (score 1):

I made a couple errors with my commands there I think, sorry. I'm not too great at commands, but I'll try.

/testfor @p {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:lever"}]} in a repeating command block, and in a chain conditional command block coming out of that, do 
/clear @a lever 1. Then another conditional chain command block out of that giving you the item.

Comment: You don't need the first command, because `/clear` only succeeds if it removed at least one item.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a dummy scoreboard called Lever with a repeating command block that sets all play Rees with a lever to 1. Then you can set a chain command block coming out of it clearing them of the item, and another command block giving them the island. Hope this helps.

Comment: And what command would that be?  Care to give an example?